# Alternating Series Convergence Area

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asked to find for which values my series will converge.
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^{5n}}{(4+(-1)^n)^{3n}}$$

after root test I think I can write :

when n is even :
$$|\frac{x^5}{5^3}| < 1$$ $$-125<x^5<125$$
when n is odd :
$$|\frac{x^5}{3^3}| < 1$$ 
$$-27<x^5<27$$

and I don't now what to write as answer, I guess $$-27<x^5<27$$ because it is included in 
$-125<x^5<125$.

*1.But if let's say my answer were $10<x<20$ and $60<x<100$ they have nothing in common here
so will my series be then divergent ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea; by the Root test, the series converges when
$\displaystyle L=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|u_n|^{1/n}<1$.

Since $\;\displaystyle|u_n|^{1/n}=\frac{|x|^5}{27}$ if n is odd and $\displaystyle|u_n|^{1/n}=\frac{|x|^5}{125}$ if n is even,

$\;\;\;\displaystyle L=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|u_n|^{1/n}=\frac{|x|^5}{27}<1 \iff |x|<3^{3/5}$.

(Since the intervals for this series are centered at 0, you will not encounter a situation where you have disjoint intervals.)